# Angular directive $compile html doesnt trigger angular methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive where i attempt to append some HTML

```
angular.module('Form').directive('remoteFieldValidation', function (Query, $q, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
           var el = angular.element('<span/>');
           var errorMessageHTML = "<span ng-show='newUserForm.email.$error.myRemoteValidator' translate='FORMS.WRONG_USERNAME'></span>";
           el.append(errorMessageHTML);
           element.parent().append(el);
           $compile(element.contents())(scope);

        }
    }
});
```

The HTML is appended however neither `ng-show` nor `translate` seems to work. Can anyone see what ive done wrong?

My html is:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="control-label" for="email" translate="FORMS.EMAIL"></label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="{{ 'FORMS.EMAIL_PLACEHOLDER' | translate }}" class="form-control"
           ng-model="CTRL.user.username" id="email" required remote-field-validation="username" name="email">
</div>
```

As you can see from the image below the HTML is added however the attributes does not work:

[image]

Comment: Where in your HTML should the `span` be added? Above or below the input/label?

Comment: @Ankh Below the input please note it is added however not working with the attributes

Comment: Could try `var errorMessageHtml = $compile("<span>...</span>")(scope);`? May not need the final `$compile` then.

Comment: @Ankh please post this as an answer this worked